# UIViewPropertyAnimator does strange things in the application life cycle

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

Help me to figure out what is happening in this scenario:

Immagine you have a view controller with the following properties

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` you do something like that

```
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
        duration: 1,
        curve: .easeOut,
        animations: {
            self.blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        })
    animator?.fractionComplete = 0
```

To see the blur effect at work, you have to put something behind it (e.g. a UIImageView).
You have also a UISlider to play with the animation:

```
@IBAction private func sliderDidChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
    animator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(sender.value)
}
```

After playing for a while you put the app in background and come back.
What do you expect to see?
For some reason the animation starts when you go in background, and when you come back the animation is in its final state!
But I noticed that this behavior is related to the `UIVisualEffectView`.
If you change other properties in the animator (for example the `opacity` or the `transform`) the animator works as I expect (nothing changes when the app goes in background).

Did I miss something or is it a UIKit bug?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Whenever the application resumes (such as in `viewWillAppear`), set the current state of your animation to your desired value.

**Explanation**

As you mentioned in your question, this is more of an issue with `UIVisualEffectView` than it is with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.

To animate a `UIVisualEffectView`'s blur interactively, an alternative solution is to pause the layer's animation by settings its `speed` to `0` and modifying the layer's `timeOffset`. I mention this because it has the side effect of not being restored to the proper `timeOffset` when the application returns from the background. I suspect something similar is occurring here.