# UIViewPropertyAnimator for NSLayoutConstraints makes view disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have a UIViewPropertyAnimator that I set up like this in `viewDidAppear`:

```
if animator == nil {
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5.0, curve: .easeInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
        guard let blockSelf = self else { return }
        blockSelf.primaryPromptLabel.alpha = 0
        blockSelf.secondaryPromptLabel.alpha = 0
        blockSelf.backArrowButton.alpha = 1
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(blockSelf.constraintsToAdd ?? [])
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(blockSelf.constraintsToRemove ?? [])
        blockSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

I am using the animator to interpolate between two mutually exclusive sets of constraints. I am using the library [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) for a drawer, and when the drawer is dragged, the UIViewPropertyAnimator's `fractionComplete` is updated based on how far the user has moved the drawer up in the `drawerChangedDistanceFromBottom` function of the Pulley library like this:

```
// Extension to clamp a value within bounds
extension ClosedRange {
    func clamp(_ value : Bound) -> Bound {
        return self.lowerBound > value ? self.lowerBound
            : self.upperBound < value ? self.upperBound
            : value
    }
}

// PulleyDrawerViewControllerDelegate in my view controller
func drawerChangedDistanceFromBottom(drawer: PulleyViewController, distance: CGFloat, bottomSafeArea: CGFloat) {
    let bottomSafeSpace = drawer.bottomSafeSpace
    let expandedHeight = drawer.visibleDrawerHeight
    let partialHeight = drawer.partialRevealDrawerHeight(bottomSafeArea: bottomSafeSpace)

    let percentExpanded = (0.0 ... 1.0).clamp(1 * (drawer.drawerDistanceFromBottom.distance-partialHeight) / (expandedHeight-partialHeight))

    animator?.fractionComplete = percentExpanded
}
```

The process as described is working as expected, until the user goes to the background and returns to the app. At that point, the views I am animating with constraints seem to simply disappear. I saw another question that indicates that the UIViewPropertyAnimator [does strange things with the lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442098/uiviewpropertyanimator-does-strange-things-in-the-application-life-cycle). Maybe something like that is causing the problem?

I also never start/finish the animator, I simply update the `fractionComplete` in `drawerChangedDistanceFromBottom`, perhaps I should? Although I don't want the animation to actually run with a 5 second duration, I just want a scrubbable animation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the cause of the issue, but one of the constraints I was adding was a height = 0 constraint for the primary and secondary labels. The labels were also in a stack view. I removed the labels from the stack view and still had the same issue. For now, I have overcome the issue by changing the animation to a `CGAffineTransform` for translation instead of adding a height = 0 constraint. It didn't work when using a `CGAffineTransform` for scale (whether I put the labels in a stack view or not).

If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know.